# Is it possible to vote to close a question as a duplicate (instead of single-handedly closing it) when you have a gold tag badge?

Tags: support, duplicates, badges, vote-to-close, privileges

Recently I acquired a gold badge for [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e).

[Gold tag badges](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold) allow a user to single-handedly mark questions with the appropriate tag as duplicates and reopen them as needed.

However, one problem I've run into is that there doesn't seem to be an option to actually *vote* to close a question as a duplicate instead of closing it straight up.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to simply vote to close instead of closing outright?

Comment: related: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=32495376#32495376

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. This was requested and denied, several times. [Quoting a community manager](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231507):

> We've no plans to make "opting out" an option. This is in keeping with existing behavior: once you gain the ability to vote to close, you can no longer flag for closing. The system trusts you more, and there's no way to tell it to trust you less.
>
> [...]
>
> And if you do make a mistake, you have the ability to immediately re-open the same question you immediately closed. Reopen votes on duplicates are binding for badge holders in the relevant tags as well.