# What privileges, exactly, come with tag badges?

Tags: support, tags, badges, privileges

I'm given to understand, based on questions like [this one](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7877/is-it-possible-to-vote-to-close-a-question-as-a-duplicate-when-you-have-a-gold), that tag badges (only gold tag badges?) come with some privileges that apply only when acting on posts with that tag.  However, I'm unable to find any description of these privileges, either in the [privileges page](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) or in the [description of tag badges](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold).

- What exactly do tag badges let you do that you couldn't otherwise?
- Do tag badges other than gold come with any privileges?
- Is it possible to make this info easier to find, or are the privileges and badge-description pages stack-wide and unable to be edited by rpg.se specifically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bronze and silver tag badges confer no privileges.

If you have a gold tag badge then you earn some privileges related to duplicate closures.

- [**The Dupehammer:**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/152515) When a question has your gold-badge tag, your votes to close it as a duplicate are **unilateral.** This means it is immediately closed as a duplicate of whatever you said because you said so. This is like what diamond moderators can do except only for duplicate votes. Your dupehammer doesn't work if you were the one that added your gold-badge tag, or if you approved the edit that added it, in order to prevent funny business. (See [uno](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268281/152515), [dos](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308573/254830).)
- Your reopen votes are also unilateral if the question has your gold-badge tag and is closed as a duplicate. (This is the reopen hammer, or the un-dupe-hammer. Its name is less cool.)
- [You can edit the duplicate targets of a question closed as a duplicate.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links) You may add or remove which questions this question is a duplicate of.

[image: little "edit" link in the duplicate close banner]

You have these powers because once you've earned a gold tag badge you have seen ***a lot*** of questions within that tag, and you probably know very well what's a duplicate of what.

Those who earn a gold tag badge find it takes some getting used to: remembering they have it, and figuring out how to use it well.

Comment: Is it editing *any* of the question's tags, or the relevant (you hold the gold) one?

Comment: @nitsua60 Looks like only the relevant tag. Updated.

Comment: Thanks!  This answers the question for *my* purposes.  Is there anything we can do to make this info more accessible?  Seems like less-than-ideal UX that you have to hunt through old meta.se posts to find out what these badges do.  (I guess having this question to link is better than nothing, but I really feel like the tag badge description page should say this stuff.)

Comment: @A_S00 You're right, and one of us can open a request on [meta.se] to have this added to the official help or badge pages somewhere.

Comment: [I did the thing.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312737/can-the-descriptions-of-tag-badges-be-updated-to-describe-the-privileges-conferr)

Comment: @A_S00 Have an updoot!

Comment: It is worth noting that this information is actual present in the help page for [duplicate closure](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates). However, that is far from the best place for someone to look who is looking for the benefits of  tag badges and it doesn't even fully explain the mechanics of it.